# How can I move the cursor between displays in Ubuntu 14?

Tags: 14.04, display

I have 2 displays connected. What should I do to move the cursor between displays?

Comment: Have you tried moving the cursor past the left /  right edge of the screen ? In the settings you should have unchecked "mirrored display", otherwise your desktop wont be extended by the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Displays have an arrangement. You can view and change it by launcher "Displays" from the dash. By moving your cursor over the edge of an display the other display is on you move it between the displays.

To be better able to do this, disable "Sticky edges" right in the display settings which you already opened.